# swiftui multiple uitextview inside foreach loop

Tags: swiftui, foreach, uitextview, swiftui-list

hi i have an observable object

```
class ListBlocks:ObservableObject {
    @Published var list = [Blocks]()
}
```

and a loop in content view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var myList = ListBlocks()

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        myList.list.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }

    .....

    List {
        ForEach(myList.list.indices, id: \.self) { i in
             WrapTest(myList: myList, i:i)
        }
        .onMove(perform: move)
    }
```

```
struct WrapTest: View {
    @ObservedObject var myList:ListBlocks
    @State var i:Int

    ........
    TestEditor(myList: myList, i:i)
```

TestEditor is a minimal UItextView with a Coordinator for write text. In makeUIView i add the text and when the selection change write the text in the main array

```
struct TestEditor: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var myList:ListBlocks
    @State var i:Int

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
         view.text = myList.list[i].text
    
    ......

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
         self.parent.myList.list[self.parent.i].text = textView.textStorage.string
```

When I write the text it is correctly updated in the main array (myList). The problem is when I move the list, the sorting changes, the indexes change and the array is updated. The foreach loop is updated and the text editor that was moved resets to its initial state, losing the text written despite being passed the updated text from the array. I have tried several ways (using a variable in binding, etc etc), but every time I am confronted with the fact that when updating the loop the editor that was moved returns without text to its initial state. Can anyone advise me on a correct approach to solve the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm scared to ask what Blocks looks like

Comment: a simple struct with id and name:String